# Retaining the id of an object after reverse filter in angularjs, javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

This is not specifically angularjs but javascript. I grab a filter from the chat example of angularjs and firebase, and this is what it looks like.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('reverse', function () {
    function toArray(list) {
      var k, out = [];
      if( list ) {
        if( angular.isArray(list) ) {
          out = list;
        }
        else if( typeof(list) === 'object' ) {
          for (k in list) {
            if (list.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
              out.push(list[k]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
        return out;
      }
      return function(items) {
        return toArray(items).slice().reverse();
      };
  });
```

But what is the problem about that code is that it removes an essential part of the object, which is it's key, that I use so that I can use that key to  query for a single object.

In my template:

```
<div ng-repeat="(id, post) in posts | orderByPriority | reverse">
    <a href="posts/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a>
</div>
```

I cannot use the `id` in `(id, post)` because it was just the index of the `reversed` array, that is 01234...

Now I added this in the reverse filter, but I can't get it to work.

```
 for (k in list) {
     if (list.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
         list[k].id = k;            // this is the one that I added.
         out.push(list[k]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: There should already be a $id on each record which you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 options
1.

```js
for (k in list) {
    if (list.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        list[k].key = k;
        out.push(list[k]);
    }
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="(id, post) in posts | orderByPriority | reverse">
    <a href="posts/{{post.key}}">{{post.title}}</a>
</div>
```

This is exactly what you tried i think. It definitely did work for me. (use post.key!!)

2.
The maybe cleaner approach would be to stick to the key / value representation of you post objets. You could create a new array `out` and push a key / value object there.

```js
for (k in list) {
    if (list.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        var newObject = {};
        newObject[k] = list[k];
        out.push(newObject);
    }
}
```

I didnt try the second approach!

Comment: have you just read my question thoroughly, I mentioned that one.